# How to split multiple character types into different columns? Using SQL in BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, multiple-columns, delimiter

I have 2 different characters ('|' and ',') in one column in Bigquery. Using SQL standard how do I split a column with the string from these characters below into multiple columns separating by '|' and ',' ?

> Inbr | Evermore | In Banner Video, Canary Island | 702B6

The code I have so far is:

Thank you here is the code scenario, how do I apply that with the other columns I need in the table?

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) Date,
Data_Source_type,
Data_Source_id,
Campaign,
Data_Source,
Data_Source_name,
Data_Source_type_name,
Ad_legacy__AdWords,
Ad_Group_Name__AdWords,
Ad_Type__AdWords,
SPLIT(Campaign,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Media,SPLIT(Campaign,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Client,SPLIT(Campaign, '|')[safe_ordinal(3)] as Market_Type,SPLIT(Campaign,'|')[safe_ordinal(4)] as Market,SPLIT(Campaign,'|')[safe_ordinal(5)] as Market_ID,
City__AdWords,
FROM `data.aud_summary'
```

Comment: Could other columns have commas in them?

Answer (score 0):

Use [REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=ja#replace) to replace your `,` to `|` before splitting the column.

```
WITH
  SampleData AS (
  SELECT
    "Inbr | Evermore | In Banner Video, Canary Island | 702B6" AS DATA )
SELECT
  a[safe_ORDINAL(1)] AS Media,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(2)] AS Client,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(3)] AS Market_Type,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(4)] AS Market,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(5)] AS Fifth,
FROM (
  SELECT
    SPLIT(REPLACE(DATA, ",", "|"),'|') AS a
  FROM
    SampleData)
```

Result

| Media | Client | Market_Type | Market | Fifth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inbr | Evermore | In Banner Video | Canary Island | 702B6 |

at last,

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(a),
  a[safe_ORDINAL(1)] AS Media,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(2)] AS Client,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(3)] AS Market_Type,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(4)] AS Market,
  a[safe_ORDINAL(5)] AS Fifth,
FROM (
  SELECT
    CAST(Date AS DATE) Date,
    * EXCEPT(Date),
    SPLIT(REPLACE(DATA, ',', '|'),'|') AS a
  FROM
    `data.aud_summary`)
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, can you explain that further with code scenario?

Comment: thank you, can you look at the additional details I added to the schema and explain how I incorporate it all together?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (as this is Campaign info - I assume the structure of string in column is consistent across rows and has same number of columns to be extracted)

```
select * except(key) from (
  select to_json_string(t) key, offset, value
  from `project.dataset.table` t,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(Campaign, r'[^,|]+')) value with offset
)
pivot(max(value) for offset in (0 as Media, 1 as Client, 2 as Market_Type, 3 as Market, 4 as Code))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> how do I apply that with the other columns I need in the table?

just add `t.*` as in below example

```
select * from (
  select t.*, offset, value
  from `project.dataset.table` t,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(Campaign, r'[^,|]+')) value with offset
)
pivot(max(value) for offset in (0 as Media, 1 as Client, 2 as Market_Type, 3 as Market, 4 as Code))
```

Comment: `how do I apply that with the other columns I need in the table?` - see update in my answer. You can provide comma separated list of column in `except()` clause after `select *`